# How to use mySQL data in PHP for loop?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to get the last ID from mySQL script and then use it in PHP for loop to display each product that way so I don't need to type separately each one of them, maybe it's not the best solution, but this is prototyping. The problem is that nothing shows on the page when it's run, if there is a number instead of $last_id then it works

```
<?php
$serverName = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

$connection = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password);

if($connection -> connect_error)
{
     die("Connection failed: " . $connection -> connect_error);
} 
$last_id = "SELECT id FROM tab_mobiteli ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1";

for($i = 0; $i < $last_id; $i++) {
     echo "<p>This is text</p>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Assigning the query to a string will not execute it. Also why not just select *all* rows, if that's what you want to display anyway?

Comment: I've been using PHP and mySQL for two days now so I'm not that familiar, I thought that the code should work if id is declared as int in the database. I want to get the exact number of products in database so each one can have it's <div> later, as I said, it's prototyping. I know that I have 15 products, but what if I would have 100, 500 or more?

Comment: You need to actually run the query. `mysqli_query()`, then fetch it. If you introduce user-variables into the query, you should prepare it and bind the values.

Answer (score 0):

How can you be sure that you'll have ID's in perfect order. There could be a number in there that does not exist, since you can later delete some rows in the database. Anyway I usualy use PDO instead of mysqli but here's the idea. Just read everything and then you can play with the output in foreach loop.

```
$stmt = $connection->query("SELECT * FROM tab_mobiteli");

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
  // here you do what you want to do for each db entry
  // for example "echo $row['id'];"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't executing the query this is why it will display nothing.
Here is an example of a query to a mysql db using `PDO`, read more about [here](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

```
<?php

$dbh = new PDO('mysql:dbname=test;host=localhost','root','root');

$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT id FROM tab_mobiteli ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 if(count($results) > 0){
    for($i = 0; $i < count($results); $i++) {
        echo "<p>$results[$i]['id']</p>";
    }
  }
?>
```